# Unable to detect the Samsung S9 device using Android Studio on Google Cloud Platform (Windows OS)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, samsung-mobile

We are unable to mount Samsung S9 to Android Studio installed on Google Cloud Platform (Windows OS).

The device is successfully mounting to local machine but does not get mounted for debugging or testing the APK on the GCP.

Any help is much appreciated?

Regards,

Comment: You want to connect Android Studio running on a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance, with a Windows OS image, to a physical Android device?

Comment: That is exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need  to enable the "RemoteFX" option on your Remote Desktop connection application

[image: Remote Desktop connection application]

I recommend you to follow [this detailed documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ff817581(v=ws.10)). Also, if you are unable to find your Android device, take a look at [this documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2653326/some-usb-devices-are-not-available-through-remotefx-usb-redirection).